# Update an element of a canvas interrupting the main loop of Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am pretty new to Python and Tkinter and thus, I cannot figure out how to implement this...

Actually, I have this GUI:

[image]

, which is created using the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

class RCP:

    global handle_comm
    global handle_rect
    global handle_res
    global spellerFrame

    global color_rect_bg, color_rect_hl, color_text_bg, color_text_hl, color_text_wa

    def __init__(self, targets, w_width, w_height):
        self.n_row = len(targets)
        self.n_col = len(targets[0])
        self.w_width = w_width
        self.w_height = w_height
        self.targets = targets
        self.canvasRoot = Tk()
        self.canvasRoot.configure(background='grey')
        self.setDefaults()
        self.canvasRoot.bind("<<foo>>", self.flashRow)

        # Initializate the main loop
        self.createGrid()
        self.canvasRoot.mainloop()

    def setDefaults(self):
        global color_rect_bg, color_rect_hl, color_text_bg, color_text_hl, color_text_wa
        color_rect_bg = '#000000'
        color_rect_hl = '#ffffff'
        color_text_bg = '#757575'
        color_text_hl = '#ffffff'
        color_text_wa = '#ffff00'
        global font_ratio_bg, font_ratio_hl
        font_ratio_bg = 0.5
        font_ratio_hl = 0.7

    def createGrid(self):
        # Calculate the maximum cell and font size that do not deform the commands' display
        cell_size = min(self.w_height / self.n_row, self.w_width / self.n_col)
        font_size = int(round(font_ratio_bg * cell_size))
        result_size = int(round(cell_size/5))

        # Create the canvas for the result text
        global handle_res
        resultLabel = Canvas(self.canvasRoot, width=self.w_width, height=result_size, bd=0,
                         highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge', background='grey')
        resultLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=self.n_col)
        handle_res = resultLabel.create_text(2, round(result_size/2),  text=' PRUEBA', fill=color_text_wa,
                            anchor='w', font=("Purisa", round(result_size/2), "bold"))

        # Create the frame for the speller
        global spellerFrame
        spellerFrame = Canvas(self.canvasRoot, width=self.w_width, height=self.w_height, bd=0,
                          highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
        spellerFrame.grid(row=1, column=0)

        # Create the grid of commands
        global handle_comm, handle_rect
        handle_comm = [[None for i in range(self.n_col)] for j in range(self.n_row)]
        handle_rect = handle_comm
        for row_index in range(self.n_row):
            for col_index in range(self.n_col):
                x1 = col_index * cell_size
                y1 = row_index * cell_size
                x2 = (col_index + 1) * cell_size
                y2 = (row_index + 1) * cell_size
                handle_rect[row_index][col_index] = spellerFrame.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=color_rect_bg)
                handle_comm[row_index][col_index] = \
                spellerFrame.create_text(((x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2), text=self.targets[row_index][col_index],
                                             fill=color_text_bg, font=("Purisa", font_size, "bold"))

    def flashRow(self):
        '''Flashes the row specified as attribute'''
        global spellerFrame
        for col_index in range(self.n_col):
            spellerFrame.itemconfig(handle_comm[1][col_index], fill=color_text_hl)


targets = [['A','B','C','D'],['E','F','G','H'],['I','J','K','L']]
myRCP = RCP(targets, 800, 600)
```

The problem is that I need to modify the color of the letters after the GUI is already displayed. This video shows the effect that I want to achieve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvfxsNpaRGI

Because of that, I have created the `flashRow` method, which flashes the 1st row when it is called. The problem is that I cannot interrupt the Tkinter's main loop for updating an element...

I have read about the `after` command, but I do not think is a suitable option for this, because I do not know in what time I'd need to call the `flashRow` method a priori.

Can I use the `generate_event` method in order to create a false-event handler to modify the color of the letters without interrumpting the loop? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you need a false-event, why not use an actual event?

Comment: Please reduce your code down to a [mcve].

Comment: I believe the effect in the video is exactly what `after` is for. You can call a method periodically to pick rows/columns to be flashed with an algorithm each time it is called.

Comment: What I undersant of an "actual event" is a mouse or keyboard event, for example. In this case, I do not want any interaction with the keyboard or the mouse. In fact, I need to generate the sequence of illuminations (i.e.,a the rows and the columns that have to be flashed) in real time. Thus, I do not know a priori what row or column need to be flashed until I about to do it...

Comment: Sure, but _when_ will the sequence of illuminations begin to appear?

Comment: This would the the time flow: 
1st: An initialization message is shown "Starting..." 
2nd: The message disappears
3rd: A sequence of illuminations is calculated
4th: Rows and columns are flashed following that sequence
5th: Another sequence is computed
6th: Rows and columns are flashed following the last sequence...

Comment: So they will start as soon as possible? If so you don't need events or false-events. I think you need to write a method to work with `after`. Basically, if you want an animation with fixed time frame, then easiest solution should include using `after`, be it initialized as false/real event or not.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the `after` method is listening for an event every 5ms, for example. Can I configure it to listen for that events all time, I mean, with a 0ms time?

Could you please indicate me how I could interact with `flashRow` using `after`? Just a small line example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`widget.after(ms, callback, *args)` calls the `callback(*args)` `ms` milliseconds after the first time it's been read by the program. So you can define a callback method, `self.flashRow` for example, and just call it with your time frame in `__init__` like:

```
self.canvasRoot.after(250, self.flashRow)
```

or:

```
self.flashRow
```

both should be fine as long as they're *before* the `mainloop` call. Then in your callback, `self.flashRow`, you need to make sure it recursively calls itself in a time frame such as 250 ms:

```
self.canvasRoot.after(250, self.flashRow)
```

---

I configured `self.flashRow` a bit to have some random flashing:

```
def flashRow(self):
    '''Flashes the row specified as attribute'''

    import random
    global spellerFrame
    _row = random.randint(0, 2)
    _color = random.choice((color_text_hl, 'grey'))
    print(_color)
    for col_index in range(self.n_col):
        spellerFrame.itemconfig(handle_comm[_row][col_index], fill=_color)
    self.canvasRoot.after(250, self.flashRow)
```

Also see, the entire configuration of the non-[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code you've provided:

```
from tkinter import *

class RCP:

    global handle_comm
    global handle_rect
    global handle_res
    global spellerFrame

    global color_rect_bg, color_rect_hl, color_text_bg, color_text_hl, color_text_wa

    def __init__(self, targets, w_width, w_height):
        self.n_row = len(targets)
        self.n_col = len(targets[0])
        self.w_width = w_width
        self.w_height = w_height
        self.targets = targets
        self.canvasRoot = Tk()
        self.canvasRoot.configure(background='grey')
        self.setDefaults()

        # Initializate the main loop
        self.createGrid()
        self.canvasRoot.after(250, self.flashRow)
        self.canvasRoot.mainloop()

    def setDefaults(self):
        global color_rect_bg, color_rect_hl, color_text_bg
        global color_text_hl, color_text_wa
        color_rect_bg = '#000000'
        color_rect_hl = '#ffffff'
        color_text_bg = '#757575'
        color_text_hl = '#ffffff'
        color_text_wa = '#ffff00'
        global font_ratio_bg, font_ratio_hl
        font_ratio_bg = 0.5
        font_ratio_hl = 0.7

    def createGrid(self):
        # Calculate the maximum cell and font size that do not 
        # deform the commands' display
        cell_size = min(self.w_height / self.n_row, self.w_width / self.n_col)
        font_size = int(round(font_ratio_bg * cell_size))
        result_size = int(round(cell_size/5))

        # Create the canvas for the result text
        global handle_res
        resultLabel = Canvas(self.canvasRoot, width=self.w_width,
                        height=result_size, bd=0,
                        highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge', background='grey')
        resultLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=self.n_col)
        handle_res = resultLabel.create_text(2, round(result_size/2),
                            text=' PRUEBA', fill=color_text_wa, anchor='w',
                            font=("Purisa", round(result_size/2), "bold"))

        # Create the frame for the speller
        global spellerFrame
        spellerFrame = Canvas(self.canvasRoot, width=self.w_width,
                                height=self.w_height, bd=0,
                                highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
        spellerFrame.grid(row=1, column=0)

        # Create the grid of commands
        global handle_comm, handle_rect
        handle_comm = [[None for i in range(self.n_col)] for j in range(self.n_row)]
        handle_rect = handle_comm
        for row_index in range(self.n_row):
            for col_index in range(self.n_col):
                x1 = col_index * cell_size
                y1 = row_index * cell_size
                x2 = (col_index + 1) * cell_size
                y2 = (row_index + 1) * cell_size
                handle_rect[row_index][col_index] = spellerFrame.create_rectangle(x1,
                                                    y1, x2, y2, fill=color_rect_bg)
                handle_comm[row_index][col_index] = \
                spellerFrame.create_text(((x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2),
                                            text=self.targets[row_index][col_index],
                                            fill=color_text_bg,
                                            font=("Purisa", font_size, "bold"))

    def flashRow(self):
        '''Flashes the row specified as attribute'''

        import random
        global spellerFrame
        _row = random.randint(0, 2)
        _color = random.choice((color_text_hl, 'grey'))
        print(_color)
        for col_index in range(self.n_col):
            spellerFrame.itemconfig(handle_comm[_row][col_index], fill=_color)
        self.canvasRoot.after(250, self.flashRow)

targets = [['A','B','C','D'],['E','F','G','H'],['I','J','K','L']]
myRCP = RCP(targets, 800, 600)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will get you started. Change `self.canvasRoot.bind("<<foo>>", self.flashRow)` to `self.canvasRoot.after(10, self.flashRow)`. This will cause flashRow to run once. At the bottom of the flashRow method, if you want to repeatedly have flashRow run, *schedule* it to run itself again using after.

```
def flashRow(self):
     '''Flashes the row specified as attribute'''
     global spellerFrame
     for col_index in range(self.n_col):
         spellerFrame.itemconfig(handle_comm[1][col_index], 
         fill=color_text_hl)
     # Put conditions or change the delay to something else,
     # but this will reschedule flashRow in 100ms repeatedly.
     self.canvasRoot.after(100, self.flashRow)
```